# How to test nodejs chaincode using ChainCodeMockStub

Tags: node.js, testing, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to test nodejs chaincode without deploying it to a hyperledger fabic network. There is a popular nodejs library called @theledger/fabric-mock-stub. Below is my unit test

```
const Chaincode = require('./index.js');
// import { ChaincodeMockStub, Transform } from "@theledger/fabric-mock-stub";
const ChaincodeMockStub = require("@theledger/fabric-mock-stub")
// You always need your chaincode so it knows which chaincode to invoke on
const chaincode = new Chaincode();
describe('Test MyChaincode', () => {
    it("Should init without issues", async () => {
        const mockStub = new ChaincodeMockStub("MyMockStub", chaincode);
        const response = await mockStub.mockInit("tx1", []);
        expect(response.status).to.eql(200)
    });
});
```

When this test is run the following error is received
`2019-04-08T18:34:55.530Z ERROR [lib/chaincode.js] uncaughtException: Missing required argument peer.address`

Does anyone know how to use this testing library? https://github.com/wearetheledger/fabric-mock-stub

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and what I noticed is that at the bottom of my chaincode js file I had

`shim.start(new Chaincode())`

If you move this line to another file or comment it out before doing tests, tests should work just fine.